# Jquery displaying controls text on screen

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is the code in the script/head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {


    $('.HideButton').click(function () {



        var theButton = $(this);

        $('#disclaimer').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            theButton.val($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
        });




        return false;
    });
    $('<h2></h2>').html($('#MessageText').val);

});
```

Code in the body:

```
    <p  id="disclaimer"  > 

    <input id="MessageText" type="text" /> //I this value to appear in an inserted h2 tag after the button toggles the <p>


</p>

<asp:Button ID="Button21" CssClass="HideButton" runat="server" Text="Hide" />
```

Comment: What appears to be the problem?

Comment: I want to get the MessageText  text and display it in <h2></h2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly - I think you want the following...

Change:

```
$(function () {
    $('.HideButton').click(function () {
        var theButton = $(this);

        $('#disclaimer').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            theButton.val($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
        });

        return false;
    });
    $('<h2></h2>').html($('#MessageText').val);
});
```

To:

```
$(function () {
    $('.HideButton').click(function () {
        var theButton = $(this);

        $('#disclaimer').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            theButton.val($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
        });
        theButton.after($('<h2></h2>').html($('#MessageText').val()));

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it..It doesnt work.. I want it to have a function like this comment.. you type, you click the button, the textbox and the button fade/toggle,,,and then this is replaced by the message typed

Comment: @DeanNorth You caught the val to val() - overlooked that

Answer (score 2):

```
$('<h2></h2>').html($('#MessageText').val);
```

val is a method, it should be...

```
$('<h2></h2>').html($('#MessageText').val());
```